# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module React native - typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, monorepo, lerna

This might be a duplicate question but have already tried few similar link solutions, but it did not work for my Monorepo(lerna architecture) project, getting below error.
Every modules have their separate configuration files.

Project structure is **Root dir -> packages -> My App with other modules**.
below configurations are placed inside **Root dir -> packages -> My App -> (All configuration files)**

[image]

My tsconfig.json has,

```
"extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
"files": ["globals.d.ts"],

"compilerOptions": {

"composite": true,
"target": "esnext",
 "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ],
 "jsx": "react-native",
"module": "commonjs",
"declaration": true,
"outDir": "./",
"esModuleInterop": true,
"strict": true,
"skipLibCheck": true

}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

jest.config.js

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  rootDir: '../',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/configs/setupTests.js'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}',
    '!<rootDir>/**/__snapshots__/*.*',
    '!<rootDir>/**/config/*.js',
    '!<rootDir>/**/constants/*.*',
    '!<rootDir>/**/*.style.*',
    '!<rootDir>/**/theme/**',
    '!<rootDir>/coverage/**',
    '!<rootDir>/store.ts',
  ],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/src/assets/',
    '<rootDir>/src/configs/',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    'graphql',
    '<rootDir>/src/*/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation|@react-native(-community)?|react-native-vector-icons|react-navigation-helpers|react-native-normalize|react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view|react-navigation/native|react-native-ratings|react-native-autocomplete-dropdown|react-native-size-matters|react-native-skeleton-placeholder|kfc-native-component-library|judokit-react-native|react-native-redash|react-native-reanimated|@react-native-cookies/cookies)',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^uuid': require.resolve('uuid'),
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}'],
  verbose: true,
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      babelConfig: true,
      tsConfig: 'packages/MyApp/tsconfig.json',
    },
  },
};
```

setupFiles.js

```
jest.mock('react-native-page-indicator', () => {
  return () => ({
    normalize: jest.fn(),
  });
});
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.22.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "11.5.1",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/lodash.get": "^4.4.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.9",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },

"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
```